# How to use the noun 'a head' in plural

Tags: nouns, british-english, comparison

How to use the noun *a head* in plural meaning? I mean the third meaning, [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/head_1?q=head). I understand I can say:

- I'm **a head** taller than my sister.

How to say when I am taller more than **a head**? Is this sentence below correct?

- *I'm **two heads** taller than my sister.*

Thanks for help.

Comment: Both sound fine to me. You could even be "a head-and-a-half" taller than your sister :D.

Comment: "Two heads taller" is grammatical but it sounds a little comical, since "a head taller" is a collocation. No one ever says "two heads taller" or "three heads taller", except facetiously, since "head" is not a bona fide unit of measure, and the image invoked is strange. You will hear "a full head taller" or "almost a head taller" and "a head taller" and "more than a head taller", but not "a head and a half taller". No multiples, no fractions.

Comment: @TRomano - That's not quite true; you can find examples in live usage like ["He stood a head and a half taller than Lance..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=pe4jBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT38&dq=%22a%20head%20and%20a%20half%22&pg=PT38#v=onepage&q=%22a%20head%20and%20a%20half%22&f=false) but I agree that it's unusual.

Comment: @stangdon: You can find almost anything if you look through a midden like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a **head** taller than my sister.
>   I'm two **heads** taller than my sister.

Both of your sentences are correct since **head** is the unit of measurement, the same would apply for inches or feet.

> I'm an *inch* taller than my sister.
>   I'm two *inches* taller than my sister.
>
> I'm a *foot* taller than my sister.
>   I'm two *feet* taller than my sister.

Using *head* as the unit of measure is a bit odd, however other nonstandard units of measure get used. [Hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_(unit)) have been used for measurement as well as the famous [Smoots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoot).